# Qt on Android. After adding AndroidManifest.xml app doesn' start

Tags: android, qt, android-manifest

I'm very new to Qt on Android.
The app runs on android with developer mode activated. I create the apk, copy it manually to android and install.
For changing the icon of the app I included AndroidManifest.xml in the project. The icon has changed indeed, but the app doesn't run any more. It closes immediately after start with a short dialog message.

I assume, it requires some resources which are not specified in the manifest. But how can I exactly know, why it stops. Are there any useful logs on android?

Comment: How did you _add_ the AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Its good to use `AndroidManifest.xml` generated in `android-build`

Comment: @MohammadKanan I have copied it from $MyApp/build-KiRaTwo-Android_for_x86_GCC_4_9_Qt_5_9_3_for_Android_x86-Release\android-build

Answer (score 1):

After building your project with working `apk`, use same manifest generated by the build (Which usually includes necessary permissions your app is likely missing now).

create a folder in project source, any name, `android-src` , then copy `AndroidManifest.xml` from your build `$build/android-build` to newly created source folder.
Next in your project `add existing Files` and select from newly created folder the `AndroidManifest.xml`, you can now edit the `AndroidManifest.xml` from your project `other files` and add/modify icon.

Your `.pro` should have an entry similar to:

```
android {
QT += androidextras
DISTFILES += \
        android/AndroidManifest.xml \
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-src
}
```

Then rebuild your project.

Comment: I have done all this, except QT += androidextras, which I think is not required for my app. My question was rather, how to find out what is wrong at run-time. A the installation I have to commit the required permissions, the proper Icon is displayed, project is built, apk is reated.

Comment: Ok, its strange as I do it frequently, adding icon as you said does not require much.